# Redirect the user upon login based on user role in drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

In drupal 8 I have two separate roles admin and manager.

If user logins with manager username and password, should be redirected to different page.

We can use module but I need to do it through custom code in drupal 8.

Please help me in the code to perform this condition in drupal 8 custom module.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use hook_user_login.
I've solved in this way:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_user_login().
 */
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

function modulename_user_login($account) {
 $routeName = 'entity.node.canonical';
 $nodeId = 1;
 $routeParameters = ['node' => $nodeId];
 $url = \Drupal::url($routeName, $routeParameters);

  $roles = $account->getRoles();
  if(in_array('administrator', $roles)){
    $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
    $response->send();
    return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use hook_form_alter to register your custom submit handler. Sample provided below.

```
    /**
     * Implements hook_form_alter().
     */
    function module_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

      //contact page form
      if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
        $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'module_contact_submit';
      }

    }

    function module_contact_submit(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {
        $redirect_path = "/redirection-path";
        $url = url::fromUserInput($redirect_path);
        $form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);
    }
```

Hope this helps
Thanks

Comment: here we are not checking for any specific roles right. need conditions to check if user is assigned role as candidate then redirect to some other page

Comment: That you can add as per your need and put this code
`$redirect_path = "/redirection-path";
$url = url::fromUserInput($redirect_path);
$form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);`
In your required condition. @Sandeep